# Redirection to Customer Pages using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP. I have a logon page with two boxes (username and password and one button (submit button).

I have a mysql database with a list of registered users. When a user logs on I want them to go to their assigned pages. An example would be Facebook you log into your account and you're taken to your page.

Here for example:

```
if($user == "Sophie")
{
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="sophie.html"</script>
}
```

This redirects the user to the correct page.

But I don't want multiple switch or else if statement for each user. How can I just have one if statement that will redirect the user to their correct page, depending upon what they've entered in the textbox.

Thanks for any help given.

I've looked online, but cannot find anything. I've played around for two days on this and haven't managed to find a solution.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

$servername = “jkjones.com";
$username = “men000”;
$password = “password123”;
$db = “customer”;

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Connection Successful to: " . $username. "<br>" ;

}

if(isset($_POST["Login"]))
{
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE name='".$user."' and password='".$pass."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($result)
    {        
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("You are logged in successfully and log in as: '.$row['$user'].'")</script>');
        }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            if($myrow['$user'] == $user)
            {
                echo '<script>location.href = "EDDIE.php?"</script>';
                ?>
                <?php       
            }
            else
            {
?>
            <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="index.html"</script>
<?php   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="errorpage.html"</script>
<?php
        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login-Index</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Username:<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter your user name."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password:<input type="text " name="pass" placeholder="Enter your password."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Log me In"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The current result is that it's going back to the 'index.html' in the else statement.

Comment: Use a logged session on login page. if the user is confirmed. then should go to their page   `sophie.html` but you need to create a command in htaccess file that will write your `"user".html` page.

Comment: you have lots of mistake in this page. dont use mysqli_fetch_array twice.

Comment: Thank you both (dean and  Dhairya Lakhera) for your feedback. I'll go away and have a look. :)